# How to match a string followed by a dynamic number and a specific string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

string = 'This is the new 5000 rupees note'

string_to_search = 'new (dynamic no.) rupees'

The numbers in the main string can be any dynamic value. How to match the string starting with 'new' and ending with 'rupees' with dynamic number in between?

Comment: please for mat code using `{ }` button, also what is desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Improved solution based on the comments:**

You can solve it with a regular expression:

```
new \d* rupees
```

For example:

```
str.match(/new \d+ rupees/g);
```

Comment: this wouldn't work all the time since d* is used for ZERO or more digits, use d+ instead so that you can make sure a digit is present

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /new[\s]?[\d]+[\s]?rupees/;
var str = `This is the new 5000 rupees note`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

you can use this site [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/) to design and test regex expressions as well as generate code in several languages

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression which searches for a string beginning with 'new' followed by an empty space, then 1 or more digits, then an empty space, then 'rupees'. I just added the alert so you can test this easily

`var str = "new 2000 rupees"
    var stringmatched= str.match(/new \d+ rupees/g);
    alert(batstringmatchedta);`

Comment: please consider up-voting or accepting the answer if this was what you where looking for @gauravatsit

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression with `String.match()`:

```js
var string = 'This is the new 5000 rupees note';

console.log(string.match(/((new+\s)+\d+(\s+rupees)+)+/g)[0].match(/\d+/g)[0]);
// or if you just want to extract number from str:
console.log(string.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
```